# how to check string.contains Either Ways

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

How do i see if 
string1 contains string2 OR 
string2 contains string1 OR
String 3 contains string 1 OR
String 1 contains string 3 OR
String 2 contains string 3 OR
string 3 contains String 2  in single line?

like i want to do

```
if ( string1.contains(string2) || string2.contains(string1) || string3.contains(string1) string3.contains(string2) || .. and so on.. ) 
{

}
```

in single check without or clause. 
In reality, i have to do this check multiple times and multiple places. So just wondering if there is a better way.

I have updated my business logic or the reason for this logic.   We have 6 Sites and we will get just the page names of the sites. i have to check the site names are similar.  The only problem is.. i donot get the site names in any particular pattern.  like for eg:

```
String1 = "/search-results"
string2= "www.foo.com/search-results?Id=1234"
string3 = "search-results"
string4= "/search-results?Id=1234"
```

and if you look at my values, you will note that if you compare any two strings with OR clause.. they will be true.

Comment: Arrays and loops man, arrays and loops. There's probably a LINQ way of doing it too.

Comment: Trying to do too much in a single line makes it hard to read. Perhaps if you give us some context for what you're trying to do, we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: Why not just define a function that does this for you? Or use Linq as @Chris already suggested.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the specific use case where you need this kind of check? I mean besides the actual C# code, what kind of business logic for your application is this implementing? What I mean it sounds like this: Any person in the database where the name of the person contains his address, or where his address contains his name, or where his address contains his spouses name, or where his spouses name contains the name of the person, or where the name of the person contains the name of the spouse, or where the spouses name contains the address.

Comment: Why not create a static method?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24706366/2547571

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your strings into an array or a list, then:

```
bool result = yourStrings
            .Where((x, idx) => 
                yourStrings.Where((y, index) => idx != index && x.Contains(y))
                .Any())
                .Any();
```

**Explanation:**

This query will take each string, and compare them with others and returns a result that indicates whether any of the strings is contains another string in the collection.

For example consider we have three strings `foo`, `bar` and `fooBar`, the steps would be like the following:

1. Take `"foo"` and check if it contains `bar` or `fooBar` (false)
2. Take `"bar"` and check if it contains `foo` or `fooBar` (false)
3. Take `"fooBar"` and check if it contains `foo` or `bar` (true because of `foo`)

I wish there is an overload of `Any` that accepts the index parameter...

Edit: here is also more efficient implementation for larger collections:

```
public static bool ContainsAny(IList<string> source)
{
     int count = source.Count;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
          for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
          {
              if (i != j && source[i].Contains(source[j]))
              {
                  return true;
              }
          }
      }

      return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have an helper method and use it :

```
public static void SomeContainsAnOther(this IEnumerable<string> @this)
{
   @this.Any(v=>@this.Count(other=>other.Contains(v)) > 1);
}
```

And use it :

```
new string[] {string1,string2,string3,..stringN}.SomeContainsAnOther();
```